# Convert a String to a Bound Method in Python

Tags: python

I'm working with the following function, which creates fake credit card numbers:

```
# !pip install Faker
from faker import Faker

def generate_data(faker_function):
  return [faker_function() for _ in range(5)]

# Function call
generate_data(Faker().credit_card_number)

# Output
['4852671922370639',
 '4852671922370639',
 '4852671922370639',
 '4852671922370639',
 '4852671922370639']
```

The function currently takes the bound method `faker_function` as an input.

I'd like to know if there is a way to pass the bound method as a string `'Faker().credit_card_number'` and then convert it to a bound method to be passed to the function.

```
def generate_data(faker_function_as_str):
# Function to convert str to bound method here
  return [faker_function() for _ in range(5)]
```

Comment: Why would you want to pass it as a string, rather than pass the method itself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

see example below - the idea is to use `getattr` and activate the function. See [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#getattr).

```
from faker import Faker

fake = Faker()

func_names = ['address', 'name', 'credit_card_number']
for func_name in func_names:
    print(getattr(fake, func_name)())
```

Example output

```
PSC 9294, Box 8014
APO AE 94944
Travis Martin
180000604338485
```

Comment: How would you apply that to the OP's requirement of passing a string like `'Faker().credit_card_number'`?

Comment: @ThierryLathuille - see the updated code. Does it answer your question?

Comment: Well, at least it seems to be what the OP expected (rather than what was in the question), so... ;)